# Error 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_vba_project'

Tags: python, vba, pandas, xlsxwriter

I've successfully Extracted vbaProject.bin but I'm still getting an error. My goal is to be able to use VBA after the information is passed to the xlsm file. This is a workaround provided by xlswriter.

```
import pandas as pd


def export(self):
    sql = "SELECT WellID,AFEno,AFEsuppno,AccountCode,AFEAmount FROM WellAFEDetails WHERE WellID = ?"
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql,self.con, params=([self.wellid_bx.get()]))
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter (r'C:\Users\bjenks\Desktop\Macro.xlsm')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Raw')
    workbook  = writer.book
    workbook.filename = (r'C:\Users\bjenks\Desktop\Macro.xlsm')
    workbook.add_vba_project(r'C:\Users\bjenks\Desktop/vbaProject.bin')
    writer.save()
```

Comment: Also, I'm following the instructions on the last answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40913896/python-vba-extract-to-get-bin-of-macro/49329853#49329853

Comment: I think you need to specify the engine parameter as "xlsxwriter" in ```pd.ExcelWriter``` in order to get the xlsxwriter workbook properties/methods.

Comment: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html

Comment: Thanks it worked! I just changed one line to this                                                  writer = pd.ExcelWriter (r'C:\Users\bjenks\Desktop\Macro.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')